# Searching custom types in plone

Tags: search, plone, content-type, dexterity

I've been tasked with setting up a community in plone. I have some custom content types created with dexterity. The problem is that I can't figure out how to search all of the fields. Under site setup -> search, I have all the relevant options selected, but I seem to be missing something (I hope it isn't too obvious).

A simplified example of the problem:

I have a custom data type "recipe", which has default fields "title" and "description" along with a text box "ingredients". I want to be able to search, for example, all recipes that contain bacon. I can't figure out how to do this. Currently only title and description are searchable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to index the fields you want to search on and then query the catalog on those index values.

Check out ["Catalog indexing strategies", Section 6.12](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/catalog).